# How do I subscribe to only the "last" notification in a group in ReactiveUI?

Tags: .net, wpf, reactiveui

Let's say I make changes to several properties, implemented with `RaiseAndSetIfChanged` setters:

```
vm.Prop1 = newValue1;
vm.Prop2 = newValue2;
```

And there's a listener:

```
this.WhenAny(a => a.Prop1, a => a.Prop2, 
    (a, b) => Unit.Default).Subscribe(_ => { Act(); });
```

What can I change to only `Act` once?  I can use Throttle() but that implies a delay.  I'd prefer to act just once, and immediately after the code is complete.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you have a few lines where you set the properties of the viewmodel. And when all of them are set you want to react to that (once). Is this part of some kind of an initialization?
If yes, why don't you add a new property IsInitialized to your viewmodel, which you set to true after the other properties and subscribe to that.

`this.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.IsInitialized).Where(i => i).Subscribe(i => Act());`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211957(v=vs.103).aspx). The resulting observable of a `Zip` will yield a value every time *both* of input observables have yielded a value, each. You could use it like this:

```
this.WhenAny(x => x.Prop1, _ => _)
    .Zip(this.WhenAny(x => x.Prop2, _ => _),
        (_, __) => Unit.Default)
    .Subscribe(_ => { Act(); });
```

Now, `Act` should be called every time both `Prop1` and `Prop2` have produced a value, but *not* when just one of them has.

Comment: If Prop1 is set twice, then Prop2 is set once, I end up triggering with the first value given to Prop1 and the value given to Prop2?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question. For the `Zip` solution to work, you're going to need to set both properties equal amount of times.